# Extract substring of 6 characters using gnu make

Tags: git, makefile, substring

I have a git hash string extracted using:

```
git describe --always --abbrev=6
```

I.e. I want to get 6 characters.
The problem is that git seem to give me 7 characters if the 6 character tag is not unique.
So I would like to extract the first 6 characters using standard make / bash commands like sed. make itself does not seem to support substrings.

Currently my make script contains this:

```
foo:=$(lastword $(subst M,,$(subst :, ,$(shell git describe --always --abbrev=6))))
```

Which could result in foo=e94181c but I like it to be just e94181 to fit in a 24 bit memory area.

Comment: Note that if you *do* trim it to a non-unique prefix, and are later handed this non-unique prefix, it may be difficult to tell which commit was actually used. (If you're lucky, the other matching IDs are non-commit objects.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would probably do this:

```
foo := $(shell git describe --always --abbrev=6 | cut -c 1-6)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is doable with only GNU make functions but the simplest is probably to use the shell used by make. If it is bash, you can, for instance, use:

```
foo := $(shell a=$$(git describe --always --abbrev=6); echo $${a:0:6})
```

Comment: This uses bash-specific features and is not portable to systems where /bin/sh is some other shell than bash (such as Debian/Ubuntu which use dash, etc.)